# android - how can i get a reference to the top level view to set an onTouch event?

Tags: android

could you please help me out or give me an example of the code i'd need to set a onTouchListener for an activity so when touched the activity will start a new activity? Just don't know how to do this and would like to see the code so I can make mine work

Thank you very much

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 2):

In your `layout.xml` give an `id` to your root `ViewGroup` element let say 'RootView'. Then in  your `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` you can get this view by calling:

```
     View root=findViewById(R.id.RootView);
```

and then you can set your `OnTouchListener`:

```
     root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class));
            //return true, the event was consumed
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate (R.layout.main_activity, null);
  setContentView (layout);
  ...
}
```